# Meta query with string starting like pattern

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I have a custom WP_Query with the following meta_query:

```
$meta_query = array();

$meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';

if(!empty($postcode)) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'postcode',
        'value' => $postcode,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
}               

if(!empty($email)) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'email_address',
        'value' => $email,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
}
```

The problem with this is WordPress is wrapping each meta value in `%%` to use as part of the `LIKE` comparison in the query e.g `WHERE meta_value LIKE '%hello@example.com%'`

Is it possible to set up a meta_query so only one percentage sign is used, so we can check if a value starts with or ends with a phrase? e.g `WHERE meta_value LIKE 'hello@%'`

Comment: Keep in mind post meta queries are super expensive and slow, if you need to filter search or query data, it should be stored using a taxonomy, not post meta

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try the `REGEXP` version:

```
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'email_address',
            'value'     => '^hello@',
            'compare'   => 'REGEXP',
        )
    )
```

where `^` matches the beginning of a string.

You can check the MYSQL reference on `REGEXP` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) for more info.

Notice that these are the [possible values](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L990) of the meta `compare` parameter:

```
'=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 
'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE','IN', 'NOT IN', 
'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'NOT EXISTS', 
'REGEXP', 'NOT REGEXP', 'RLIKE'
```

according to the WordPress 3.9.2 [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L990).

From the MYSQL [ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html):

```
Name        Description
------------------------------------------------------
NOT REGEXP  Negation of REGEXP
REGEXP      Pattern matching using regular expressions
RLIKE       Synonym for REGEXP
```

Comment: Great stuff, thanks very much. It's a shame they don't list `REGEXP` as a valid compare value in the docs (From http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query `Possible values are '=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'EXISTS' (only in WP >= 3.5), and 'NOT EXISTS' (also only in WP >= 3.5). Default value is '='.`)

Comment: I updated the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Accepted_Arguments) with these extra parameters: `REGEXP`, `NOT REGEXP` and `RLIKE`.