# Sort users by "birthday" using WP_User_Query

Tags: wp-query, users, sql

I have created user meta that holds user birthday (birthday).

birthday is date field.

Now i am trying to figure how to sort (get) all users that have birthday based on specific month.

I have created drop menu that holds all the months.

```
function users_months_dropdown() {
?> 
<select name="month" id="month" onchange="" size="1">
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<?php
        submit_button( __( 'Filter Date' ), 'secondary', 'filter_date_action', false );
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_users', 'users_months_dropdown' );
```

and now i stack with the query

i also try

```
function extended_user_searchs( $user_query ){
    if( isset( $_GET['month'] ) && !empty( $_GET['month'] ) ) {
        $date = $_GET['month'];
        $user_query->query_where .= " AND MONTH(birthday) = $date";
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'extended_user_searchs' );
```

Comment: The ["custom fields" section]( https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) in the Codex doesn't help?

Comment: Hi @s_ha_dum, How can you compare value only by month and not full date?

Comment: By *sort* here you mean to *filter*? How do you store the birthday dates?

Comment: Hi @birgire yes i mean filter to get new list in users.php based on filter. i store the date like dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Hi @Pieter Goosen i use datepicker and dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy' this is for hebrew language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### User Meta Query with `RLIKE`:

If the birth date is stored like `dd/mm/yyyy`, in the user meta, then you could find all *August* birthday users with the following meta query:

```
'meta_query' => [
    [
        'key'     => 'birthday',
        'value'   => '/08/',
        'compare' => 'RLIKE'
    ],
]
```

You could also consider storing the birthday month additionally in the user meta.

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/159433/26350) I've listed the available meta comparisons.

### Applied to your code snippet:

**Part #1**

Here's how you can apply this to your code example:

```
/**
 * Setup the user meta query for the current birth month
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_users', function( $user_query ) 
{
    // User input:
    $birthmonth = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'birthmonth', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    // Setup the meta query:
    if( $birthmonth ) 
    {
        $user_query->query_vars['meta_key']     = 'birthday';
        $user_query->query_vars['meta_value']   = zeroise( $birthmonth, 2 );
        $user_query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = 'RLIKE';
    }
} );
```

where we use the `pre_get_users` hook instead of the `pre_user_query` and use the handy `zeroise()` function - it's informative to check out the `\WP_Locale` class.
We will use it's `get_month()` method in the second part here below.

Note that in your current attempt of directly modifying the SQL query, 
the `birthday` field is treated as a part of the `wp_users` table.
Also the `INNER JOIN`, on the `wp_usermeta` table, is missing.

You must also validate/sanitize the user input.

**Part #2**

The second part is modified to:

```
/**
 * Add a birth month filter to the users table
 */    
add_action( 'restrict_manage_users', function()
{   
    global $wp_locale;

    // User input:
    $birthmonth = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'birthmonth', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    // Birthmonth select box: 
    print '<select name="birthmonth" id="birthmonth" onchange="" size="1">';
    printf( '<option value="">%s</option>', __( 'Birthmonth' ) );
    foreach( range(1,12) as $month )
    {
        printf( 
            '<option value="%d" %s>%s</option>', 
            $month, 
            selected( $birthmonth, $month ), 
            $wp_locale->get_month( $month )  
        );
    } 
    print '</select>';
} );
```

where we use `birthmonth` instead of `month`, to avoid name collision.

I also added the default state, without any `birthmonth` selected.

Also added the handy `selected()` function, to show the current selected option.

The month names are defined in the `\WP_Locale` class and the class instance is available through the global `$wp_locale` object.

Comment: thanks but seems i cant get this work. i also update my quasion and add the "query" i have tried.

Comment: I updated the answer with a workable code example, dependend on the date format `dd/mm/yyyy` that you mentioned in a comment above @need-help

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. by the way, i get this work some time after i have post this question. i make this work using `pre_get_users` and using `$query->query_vars`