# Get every post with value in meta key

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I am trying to get every post, that has a specific URL in the meta key `_cornerstone_data`. From the WordPress documentary I was able to build this query, that probably gets me close to what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    array(
        'key' => '_cornerstone_data',
        'value' => $attachment_url,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
);
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );

$mysql =$meta_query->get_sql(
    'post',
    $wpdb->posts,
    'ID'
);
```

The result is an array that looks like this:

```
'join' => string 'INNER JOIN fx30k_postmeta ON ( fx30k_posts.ID = fx30k_postmeta.post_id )'
'where' => string 'AND ( ( fx30k_postmeta.meta_key = '_cornerstone_data' AND fx30k_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{c6fc…
    AND ( ( fx30k_postmeta.meta_key = '_cornerstone_data' AND fx30k_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{c6fc239abf1a24a4f555ce84bb7edf17dd16d1cd29f38c738529c38aafc546ff}https://usd1.wireless-empire.de/wp-content/uploads/usd-ISO-27001-Foundation-Seminar-2018.pdf{c6fc239abf1a24a4f555ce84bb7edf17dd16d1cd29f38c738529c38aafc546ff}' )
)
```

However, I don't know what to do with this result and I didn't find any documentary or tutorial explaining this. How can I further use this, to get the posts that I am looking for?

---

**NEW APPROACH**

This is my new approach to the problem, incorporating some of the suggestions here. However, I get a lot of wrong results:

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    'post_type'  => array( 'post', 'page' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'   => '_cornerstone_data',
            'value' => $attachment_url,
            'compare'    => 'LIKE',
        )
    ),
);
$meta_query      = new WP_Query( $meta_query_args );
$posts = $meta_query->posts;
```

When I put it in plain SQL, this is what should be happening:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE  `meta_key` =  '_cornerstone_data'
AND  `meta_value` LIKE  '%https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/this.pdf%'
```

This query actually returns the correct result. How do I put this in a `WP_QUERY`?

---

**Printing out the SQL query that is being generated with my query, it looks like this:**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) JOIN wp_icl_translations t
ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id
AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', wp_posts.post_type) WHERE 1=1 AND (
( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_cornerstone_data' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{645cebb1ce3cff4f917092440a092979319a39817e68ccd213b321a8cef9f388}https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/this.pdf{645cebb1ce3cff4f917092440a092979319a39817e68ccd213b321a8cef9f388}' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( ( ( t.language_code = 'de' OR 0 ) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post','page','x-portfolio' ) ) OR wp_posts.post_type NOT IN ('post','page','x-portfolio' ) ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I don't know what this very long string inside this query is supposed to be. It's where there should actually be `%`. But even when I take this query, replace the `%` and try it out on my database (with phpMyAdmin), it doesn't return the right results.

Comment: You want posts, not meta values, therefore you should use `WP_Query` with the `meta_query` parameter. There are tons of articels out there about this subject.

Comment: Why are you using LIKE for what seems like an exact match? Also the string of chars is normal for a LIKE query

Comment: It's not an exact match. The string appears somewhere in the content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    'meta_query'=>array(
        array(
            'key' => '_cornerstone_data',
            'value' => $attachment_url,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    )
);

$meta_query = new WP_Query( $meta_query_args );

$posts = $meta_query->posts;
```

Comment: I tried it your way, as well as a similar code with only some changes, which both returned way too many results.

Comment: Did you try without 'relation'=>'AND'?

Comment: Also try to put url into brackets ' "https:// ... " ', check without % sign and see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/159433/147957

Comment: Neither of these work. I printed out the SQL query that is being generated with my query and it doesn't even contain my meta field... see my post above.

Comment: I deleted the "meta_" part from the query and I have the meta field in my result at least. But I have a weird very long string of characters in my SQL query now.